# Do CMake modules need to honor defines such as NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH

Tags: path, cmake, system, environment

I need to be very strict as to which external software packages my software links to. To do this I set

```
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/root/of/software/that/the/build/may/use
-DNO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH=true
-DNO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH=true
-DNO_DEFAULT_PATH=true
```

It seems that some cmake modules do not honor these settings. An example is FindTCL.cmake provided with CMake 3.8.1. Here an excerpt from the file:

```
set(TCLTK_POSSIBLE_INCLUDE_PATHS
  "${TCL_LIBRARY_PATH_PARENT}/include"
  "${TCL_INCLUDE_PATH}"
  ${TCL_FRAMEWORK_INCLUDES}
  "${TCL_TCLSH_PATH_PARENT}/include"
  /usr/include/tcl${TCL_LIBRARY_VERSION}
  /usr/include/tcl8.6
  ...
)

if(WIN32)
  set(TCLTK_POSSIBLE_INCLUDE_PATHS ${TCLTK_POSSIBLE_INCLUDE_PATHS}
  "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Scriptics\\Tcl\\8.6;Root]/include"
  ...
  "$ENV{ProgramFiles}/Tcl/include"
  "C:/Program Files/Tcl/include"
  "C:/Tcl/include"
  )
endif()

find_path(TCL_INCLUDE_PATH
  NAMES tcl.h
  HINTS ${TCLTK_POSSIBLE_INCLUDE_PATHS}
)
```

This leads to my build using Tcl from Active State installs on Windows and `/usr/include` on Linux which I did not expect.
Should FindTCL.cmake honor `NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH` (and similar settings) and not add ActiveState and `/usr/include` if it is set?

Answer (score 0):

*NO_CMAKE_SYSTEM_PATH*, *NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH* and *NO_DEFAULT_PATH* are **not the variables**, but options for `find_library` and other `find_*` commands.

(Simple test for thing being [CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-variables.7.html): Most of CMake *variables* are prefixed with `CMAKE_`.)

When set *CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH* variable, other search paths may be disabled through `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_*` variables "family":

```
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_INCLUDE=ONLY # search header files only under root path
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_LIBRARY=ONLY # search libraries only under root path
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_PROGRAM=ONLY # search programs only under root path
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_PACKAGE=ONLY # search packages only under root path
```

Note, that [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH.html) variable for CMake means a "filesystem re-root". E.g. on Linux it expects libraries under `${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}/usr/lib`. However, for find a library installed into `${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}` directory, you may additionally set

```
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=/root/of/software/that/the/build/may/use
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/
```

If your directory is just a collection of libraries, and libraries are installed into it (the directory is used as *install prefix*), it is more natural to set [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable instead:

```
-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/root/of/software/that/the/build/may/use
```

Note, that `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable is just a *preference*: If CMake doesn't find the library here, it will continue to search in system-specific directories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer which will help me write better CMakeList.txt files. 
When it comes to writing FindXXX.cmake or XXXConfig.cmake files or fixing broken ones I gather from your answer that variables such as NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH given on cmake invocation must be used by FindXXX.cmake in their call to find_*. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, it is `FindXXX.cmake` who decides, whether or not to use *NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH* and other options for find things.

Comment: My assumption: Variables such as NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH have a defined meaning in cmake. Therefore the FindXXX.cmake files must evaluate NO_SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PATH ... if the result would be influenced by this variable.